# Image returned by Symfony 4 not showing in React Native

Tags: image, reactjs, symfony, native

I've written the following code to let my Symfony backend return an image:

```
    /**
   * @Route("/project/{id}/image", methods={"GET"}, name="get_project_image")
   */
   public function getImage($id) {
     $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Project::class);
     $project = $repository->find($id);

     $filePath = $this->getParameter('project_image_directory').$project->getImage();
     return new BinaryFileResponse($filePath);
   }
```

This image is also located in my public directory, so it's accessible through the following URL: http://192.168.1.128:8000/uploads/project/5f5d8575ebd98fa7fa970ad2d910314f.jpeg

Both URL's return an image when I open them in my browser, however, only the second shows up in my React Native app...

Comment: do you have any security protecting this url?